# pthread concepts in linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have some questions about pthreads in linux:

1. Is it the case that `pthread_t` is it a datatype similar to `int` and `char` indicating we are defining a thread?
2. If so, how much size does it take? 2 bytes or 4 bytes?
3. Does the compiler allocate memory to `pthread_t thread1` immediately after that statement or does it wait until it a `pthread_create()` call?
4. How does one set the thread attributes, and what is their typical use?
5. Can one only pass more than one argument in the `pthread_create()` call?  If so, how?

I have lots of things on my mind like this.  Please also feel free to suggest any good sites or documents to read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering the questions one by one, though not necessarily in the same order:

**Is `pthread_t` a data type similar to `int` or `char`, indicating we are defining a thread ? Does the compiler allocate memory to `pthread_t thread1` immediately after that sentence or does it wait until it finds the `pthread_create()` call**

`pthread_t` is a type similar to `int` and it's created when you define it, not when you call `pthread_create`. In the snippet:

```
pthread_t tid;
int x = pthread_create (&tid, blah, blah, blah);
```

it's the *first* line that creates the variable, although it doesn't hold anything useful until the return from `pthread_create`.

**How much size does a `pthread_t` take, 2 bytes or 4 bytes?**

You shouldn't care how much space it takes, any more than you should care how much space is taken by a `FILE` structure. You should just use the structure as intended. If you *really* want to know, then `sizeof` is your friend.

**Any good information about how to set the thread attributes?**

If you want to use anything other than default attributes, you have to create an attributes variable first and then pass that to the `pthread_create` call.

**Can we only pass one argument in the `pthread_create` function to the function? Can't we send 2 or 3 arguments in the `pthread_create()` function to the called thread?**

While you're only allowed to pass *one* extra parameter to the thread , there's nothing stopping you from making this one parameter a pointer to a structure holding a hundred different things.

---

If you're looking for information on how to use pthreads, there's plenty of stuff at the end of a Google search but I still prefer the dead-tree version myself:

[image: PThreads programming book, ISBN 13: 978-1-56592-115-3, ISBN 10: 1-56592-115-1]

Answer (score 2):

> how much size does it take

`pthread_t` uses `sizeof pthread_t` bytes.

> and we can only pass one argument in the pthread_create to the function not more than one? cant we send 2 or 3 arguments in the pthread_create() function to the called thread?

All you need is one argument. All you get is one argument. It's a `void *` so you can pass a pointer to **whatever you want.**  Such as a structure containing multiple values.

> i have lots of things on my mind like this suggest any good sites or documents to read

Have a look at the `pthread` man pages, [online](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) or in your shell of choice (`man pthread`, `man pthread_create`, etc.). I started out reading some [basic lecture slides](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/s11/handouts/threads1.pdf) (here's [the sequel](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/s11/handouts/threads2.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_t` could be *any* number of bytes.  It could be a char, an int, a pointer, or a struct...  But you neither need to know nor to care.  If you need the size for allocation purposes, you use `sizeof(pthread_t)`.  The only type of variable you can assign it to is another `pthread_t`.

The compiler may or may not allocate the resources associated with the thread when you define a `pthread_t`.  Again, you do not need to know nor to care, because you are required to call `pthread_join` (or `pthread_detach`) on any thread you create.  As long as you follow the rules, the system will make sure it does not leak memory (or any other resource).

Attributes are admittedly a bit clumsy.  They are held in an `pthread_attr_t` object, which again could be represented as an integer, pointer, or entire struct.  You have to initialize it with `pthread_attr_init` and destroy it with `pthread_attr_destroy`.  Between those two, you use various `pthread_attr_...` calls to set or clear attributes, and then you can pass it as part of one or more `pthread_create` calls to set the attributes of the new threads.

Different implementations can and will handle all of these things differently.

[LLNL has a decent set of introductory information](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Answer (score 0):

Look into `pthread.h` file to get more information. On my system, `pthread_t` is defined as an `unsigned long int`. But I guess this is platform dependent, since it is defined into `bits/pthreadtype.h`.

Comment: This is very platform dependent.  On some systems it is a `struct`.